# mini display port / HDMI on Macbook with linux

Tags: 14.04, hdmi, macbook

I have a macbook air running ubuntu 14.04 and i want to connect it to an external monitor throught the only output that it has which is a mini display port. The adaptator worked with mac OS but with linux doesn't. Someone has an idea?
Thank you.

Comment: On a [macbook air 2012](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP650) with Ubuntu 21.10: the minidisplay port is not working too (standard installation)